# ReSharper 9.0 styling: BSD indention is slightly off

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper, resharper-9.0

**Problem:**

Can't get the wanted styling from ReSharper.
See below **current** and **expected** styles.

---

**ReSharper info:**

I'm using ReSharper 9.0.0.0 in C# environment, with these two relevant settings:

- `Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Braces Layout >`
  `Array and object initizlizer: At next line (BSD style)`
- `Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Other >`
  `Array, object and collection initizlizer: V (checked)`

The 2nd setting makes the `{` aligned with the `new`, which is what I want.

The 1st setting *should* make the code block within the `{` indented +1, but it seems to be doing `Whitesmiths` style (indented +0), instead of the wanted `BSD` style.

---

**Visual Studio info:**

2013 community version

---

**The current style is:**

[image: Current style]

**The expected style is:**

[image: Expected style]

Is this a known bug in RS9.0 or am I looking at the settings wrong?
How can I get the styling as expected?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I'm using your two settings and it works exactly as expected.

Comment: Do you know what other settings might affect this?

Comment: No idea but it must be something you did: I coincidentally reinstalled my OS 2 days ago so these are brand-spanking-new Resharper settings.

Comment: Could you please export your settings for me, and I'll compare? Can be easily done with: `ReSharper > Manage Options > Import From > Export to File` (counter intuitive much?)

Comment: There are just the Code Editing settings: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2imzdmajtgwtl9/rssettings.DotSettings?dl=0

Comment: I believe it is the `CodeStyle` settings that I need. Even just the child `CodeFormatting`.

Comment: I changed the file so it includes all settings. Good luck!

Comment: Found the culprit, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem originated from a different setting:

`Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Other`
`Continuous line indent multiplier` was 0, should've been 1.